# Help with fleet combat strategy game AI

Tags: algorithm, ai

can you tell me how to implement a game AI like the sea battle Ai in NAPOLEON:total war.

I want to finish a small game,which the ship can occupy the island to produce more ships and my fleet can battle with the others.
can you give me an example,or what should i learn to finish it.
Thank you~

Comment: This question is unreasonably broad for this site. You need to investigate this yourself, if you come across a specific problem while trying to implement this, then ask a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

This article could help you: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1535/designing_ai_algorithms_for_.php